# pass configure arguments to install packages in R

Tags: r, install.packages

I am trying to install a package in `R` from the CRAN repository.  I have to pass a flag at the *configure* stage, but I can't figure out how to do it in `install.packages`:

```
> install.packages("Rmpfr")

..........
checking mpfr.h usability... no
checking mpfr.h presence... no
checking for mpfr.h... no
configure: error: Header file mpfr.h not found;
**maybe use --with-mpfr-include=INCLUDE_PATH**
```

(Note:  I have MPFR installed in a custom location, since I am not root).

**But how do I pass a specific flag with argument to the `install.package` command of `R`?**  .e.g  " --with-mpfr-include=/path/to/mpfr/include "

based on the `install.packages` man page, I have tried:

```
install.packages("Rmpfr" , INSTALL_opts = "--with-mpfr-include=/path/to/mpfr/include")

install.packages("Rmpfr" , configure.args = "--with-mpfr-include=/path/to/mpfr/include")

install.packages("Rmpfr" , configure.vars = "--with-mpfr-include=/path/to/mpfr/include")
```

But none of them worked, with the same error.

Comment: By "none of them worked," you mean all gave the exact same error message? I would guess the `configure.args =` syntax should be correct. And did you verify that header file is present at the path specified?

Comment: yes, they all give the same error message.  And yes, the header mpfr.h is indeed in the provided path.

Answer (score 21):

I just stumbled upon this problem myself, trying to install [udunits2](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/udunits2/index.html) as a dependency of [ggforce](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggforce/index.html). [This answer](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/install-packages-and-configure-args-tp917554p917555.html) on the R devel mailing list worked in my case: I needed to pass a named character vector to `configure.args` keyed by the *package name*. This should would work for your case, then:

```
install.packages("Rmpfr",
  configure.args = c(Rmpfr = "--with-mpfr-include=/path/to/mpfr/include"))
```