# install_github with --no-multiarch argument

Tags: r, devtools

I want to install a package from github and skip the installation for arch i386.
Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37287226/pass-configure-arguments-to-install-packages-in-r) question (unfortunately not answered), I tried the following with no avail:

```
library(devtools)
install_github("ramnathv/rCharts", configure.args = "--no-multiarch")
install_github("ramnathv/rCharts", configure.args = list(rCharts = "--no-multiarch"))
install_github("ramnathv/rCharts", configure.args = list(`ramnathv/rCharts` = "--no-multiarch"))
install_github("ramnathv/rCharts", configure.vars = "--no-multiarch")
install_github("ramnathv/rCharts", configure.vars = list(rCharts = "--no-multiarch"))
install_github("ramnathv/rCharts", configure.vars = list(`ramnathv/rCharts` = "--no-multiarch"))
```

I can achieve my goal by downloading the package and installing via

```
R CMD INSTALL --no-multiarch rCharts.tar.gz
```

How can I specify the "--no-multiarch" argument when using devtools::install_github ?

I am running R3.3.0 with devtools_1.12.0. Using packrat_0.4.7-1 for creating a local library.

See the sessionInfo below:

```
R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows Server >= 2012 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] nxPacMan_0.4.0  devtools_1.12.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] httr_1.2.1      R6_2.2.0        tools_3.3.0     withr_1.0.2     curl_2.3        memoise_1.0.0   git2r_0.16.0    digest_0.6.10  
[9] packrat_0.4.7-1
```

Thank's a lot for your help.

Markus

Answer (score 12):

This worked for me:

```
devtools::install_github("snowflakedb/dplyr-snowflakedb", 
                         INSTALL_opts=c("--no-multiarch"))
```

Answer (score 7):

The only way that I found working for me is setting the options:

```
library(devtools)
options(devtools.install.args = "--no-multiarch")   
install_github("ramnathv/rCharts")
```